# EPPlus & C#: How to apply conditional formatting on range instead of attaching to each cell

Tags: c#, epplus

I need to apply conditional formatting on range instead of attaching conditional formatting to each cell. the way i am doing right now that is slow process. i have huge cell to which i am attaching conditional formatting in for loop which is getting slow for me. so i am looking for way to do the same in range which may reduce few iteration.

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("Test.xlsx");
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;

    var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
    currentWorksheet.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;

    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
        ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("$A$" + i);

        int j = 11 - i;
        string _statement = "=$A$" + i + ">$A$" + j;
        var f = currentWorksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
        f.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Green;
        f.Formula = _statement;

        _statement = " =$A$" + i + "<$A$" + j;
        f = currentWorksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
        f.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Red;
        f.Formula = _statement;
    }


    package.Save();
}
```

hopefully it is clear that what i am doing. i am comparing value with each cell to a specific cell. if value is less then color will red otherwise color will be green.

my issue is i am iterating in for loop to attaching the conditional formatting to each cell which is getting slow. when i have to iterate in many cell then for loop will take some time. so i like to know can i do the same with range instead of attaching conditional formatting to each cell.

Please advise how to do the same with range but each cell value in range will be compared against a specific cell value. thanks

Comment: So every cell will have a unique formula?  Not sure you could do that in a single range (or 2 in this case - odds and evens).  Are you able to show what you are trying to do in Excel itself?

Comment: I guess it is about referencing current cell value in validation formula for a range of cells. Same question for me. Does anyone know if it is feasible with EPPlus lib?

It should be clearer when looking at this screenshot:
https://snipboard.io/DTWV69.jpg